# Reading array from Spreadsheet Data VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm sending a range into an array in VBA.  But, when I try to reference parts of the array, I get a "Subscript Out of Range" error.  I know that the range is successfully being transferred, because I can then send the array back into a different range.

```
Dim LastClmn() As Variant   'The last column of brake data
Set RangeSet = ws.Range("RJ2:RJ" & ii)
LastClmn() = RangeSet
Msgbox LastClmn(4)
```

Referencing a piece of the array is what causes the error

Comment: `Msgbox LastClmn(4,1)`Should do it.  Though it appears to be a 1 dimensional array it is actually a 2 dimensional array.  So you need to put the `,1`.

Comment: This works. Thanks, Scott!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `LastClmn(4,1)`

I found it by using the Locals Window under View in the menu bar.